# Shell script error - bad substitution - principle

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am new in shell scripting and all questions I found about this was so complicated that I decided to ask the question about the principle of this error.
I have a test.sh file which looks like:

```
var1="I love Suzi Suzi and Marry"
var2="Sara"
echo "${var1//Suzi/$var2}"
```

if I run it in terminal via **sh test.sh** I am getting this error - Bad substitution. Can somebody tell me please what is wrong with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I run it in terminal via `sh test.sh`

There's your problem. `${parameter/pattern/string}` is `bash` syntax, not vanilla `sh`. Run it via `bash test.sh` (And/or put an appropriate [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in your script and make it executable so you can just run `./test.sh`).